# How to center table in FPDF using PHP

Tags: php, fpdf

I am generating a table by using FPDF library as a PDF document generator.
The problem is the table that contain the data won't centered although I've tried to write 'C' in the $pdf->Cell() parameter. The output is aligned to the left side as shown below.

[image: Not centered]

And also why the cell is moved into the bottom while there're still spaces on the right when I add a new column(*5 column*) as shown below.

[image: Overlap]

I've tried to add 'C' parameter inside of all the cell related like this
`$pdf->Cell(190,7,'Some text',0,1,'C');`,

And also using `$pdf->SetXY(20,20);` a solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330311/fpdf-cell-not-centering-on-page-php)
But it still doesn't work.

My current code is:

```
<?php

require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->Image('some_image.png',10,10,30,15);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(190,7,'Some title',0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
$pdf->Cell(190,7,'Jl. Some address',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(10,7,'',0,1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
$pdf->Cell(190,7, $somestring1 ,0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->Cell(190,7,'to',0,1,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
$pdf->Cell(190,7, $somestring2 ,0,1,'C');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
$pdf->Cell(10,7,'',0,1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(6,6,'NO',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(23,6,'TUJUAN',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(25,6,'PEMINJAM',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(35,6,'KENDARAAN',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(27,6,'JAM BERANGKAT',1,1,'C');
// If I add this cell, then i'll overlap/move to the bottom
$pdf->Cell(27,6,'JAM PULANG',1,1,'C');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',8);
$query = mysqli_query($someconn, "SELECT somequery");

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->Cell(6,6,$i++,1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(23,6,$row['sometable'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(25,6,$row['sometable'],1,0);
    $pdf->Cell(35,6,$row['sometable']." ".$row['sometable'],1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(27,6,$row['sometable'],1,1,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(30,6,$row['sometable'],1,1,'C');
}

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: The `centering` only applies to individual cells not to the overall look and positioning of the data. For the 2nd part of your question your width totals plus the border on each cell exceed the width of your page causing the overflow.

Comment: So, how to fix it sir?
I tried to center the first cell according to the FPDF reference that says "The upper-left corner of the cell corresponds to the current position. The text can be aligned or centered. After the call, the current position moves to the right or to the next line." But still, doesnt't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flowing to the next page appears to be caused by this line

`$pdf->Cell(27,6,'JAM BERANGKAT',1,1,'C');`

containing a 1 right before the `'C'` (the one says go to the next line). Change it to

`$pdf->Cell(27,6,'JAM BERANGKAT',1,0,'C');`

and that additional cell should not start on a new line.

For centering, with no margins set your page width should be 210. The width of all of your cells is 153 which means that should fit just fine.

To center things on the page use `SetLeftMargin` to half of the difference between the page width, 210, and the total width of your columns, 153 which comes out to 28. Right after you create the instance of FPDF set the margin before starting a new page.

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->SetLeftMargin(28);
$pdf->AddPage();
```

Comment: Yes sir you right! I forgot to pay attention at this line `$pdf->Cell(27,6,'JAM BERANGKAT',1,1,'C');`. But the '1' should be at the end of the column line, to start a new row.

However I don't understand about the centering calculation, I just estimating it in about `$pdf->SetLeftMargin(32);` **and** I placed it before the body row (below header) as what I want is only the body to be centered. Thanks a lot sir!